# Nodejs asynchronicity execution

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am working with my company database and I am trying to set up a route . The data that I get is an array of JSON of 1000 values.

Here's the function--

```
router.get('some_route', function(req, res, next){
var ress = [];
var name = req.params.name;
baWelcomeController.autoComplete(name).then(function(succ){
    var x = Object.values(succ[0][0]); 
    res.status(200).send(x);
}).catch(function(err){
  res.status(404).send(err);
    console.log("error in router.get", err);
});

});
```

Now look at the `object.values` part of my code , from internet i got to know its an O(n) function so nodejs should push it into the call-stack  and in the meanwhile execute other functions, but what is happening is I am getting the response as expected. The number of values in succ[] are 1000, so I wrote another function commenting Object.values and writing a for loop instead-

```
router.get('some_route', function(req, res, next){
var ress = [];
var name = req.params.name;
baWelcomeController.autoComplete(name).then(function(succ){

    var x = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
        x += i;
    res.status(200).send(x);
}).catch(function(err){
  res.status(404).send(err);
    console.log("error in router.get", err);
});

});
```

Now I don't get value of x as response I get an empty object. I am finding this behavior weird! Could someone explain this to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It think this is probably express turning your number into an object.   According to the docs send can accept a Buffer, String, or Array.

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send

Try something like: res.status(200).send({num: x});

Comment: hey since the complexity is O(n) so if n >= 10000000 the res that i will get is empty. isn't it?

Comment: The complexity shouldn't change your result no matter what n is.   O(n) simply means that as the size increases (n) the time it takes to run your algorithm will increase linearly.   So if n=1 took 1 sec, n=100 would take 100s.  This is better than say O(n^2) where runtime would increase much faster. n=1 is 1 sec, n=100 would be 10,000 sec.  But not as good as say O(log n) n=1 => 1 sec, n=100 => 2 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Dear Since Node is Asynchronous Programming Language , internally it will skip functions which takes larger time for execution and it will first send response.

So u must use Synchronous Concept inside node

u can refer [async package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)

[sync package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync)